# How to merge two collections keeping the document with highest timestamp in MongoDB

Tags: json, database, mongodb, go, import

I'm creating a MongoDB client for a Go Application, using the [MongoDB Go Driver](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/go/current/). In particular, I have two databases with one collection each. These collection can be modified asynchronously by different clients, so i need to periodically synchronize them, keeping the most recently edited document, among those with the same `id` field

The two databases are stored on **different hosts**, so i need to **export** the collection from one host using `mongoexport` and **import** into the other host using `mongoimport`.

I already tried using `mongoimport --collection=myColl --mode=merge`, but this doesn't fit my goal because simply overrides the conflicting documents from `myColl` with the imported ones.

My idea is to import the json into a temp collection, but i don't know how to compare the timestamps during the aggregation/merge process.

My collections are structured Like this, any idea?

#### Collection 1

```
{"_id":"K1","value":"VAL1","timest":{"$date":"2021-09-26T09:05:09.942Z"}}
{"_id":"K2","value":"VAL2","timest":{"$date":"2021-09-26T09:05:10.234Z"}}
```

#### Collection 2

```
{"_id":"K2","value":"VAL3","timest":{"$date":"2021-09-26T09:15:09.942Z"}}
{"_id":"K3","value":"VAL4","timest":{"$date":"2021-09-26T09:15:10.234Z"}}
```

#### Desired Behaviour

##### Conflict

```
    {"_id":"K2","value":"VAL2","timest":{"$date":"2021-09-26T09:05:10.234Z"}}
{"_id":"K2","value":"VAL3","timest":{"$date":"2021-09-26T09:15:09.942Z"}}[LATEST]
```

##### Output

```
{"_id":"K1","value":"VAL1","timest":{"$date":"2021-09-26T09:05:09.942Z"}}
{"_id":"K2","value":"VAL3","timest":{"$date":"2021-09-26T09:15:09.942Z"}}
{"_id":"K3","value":"VAL4","timest":{"$date":"2021-09-26T09:15:10.234Z"}}
```

Comment: The mongoimport is not really built for that. I would take the route of sending all the data from one host to the other by HTTP Post. The receiver can then merge the data with any logic you want, update it's database and respond with the merged data back to the first host, who can then go ahead and update it's own data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$merge`

The bellow merges `testdb1.coll` to `testdb2.coll` based on same `_id`
And keeps the document with the latest date. If `_id` is not found, then document is inserted.

Data in

testdb1.coll

```
[{"_id" "K2","value" "VAL3","timest" (date "2021-09-26T09:15:09.942Z")}  
 {"_id" "K3","value" "VAL4","timest" (date "2021-09-26T09:15:10.234Z")}]
```

testdb2.coll

```
[{"_id" "K1","value" "VAL1","timest" (date "2021-09-26T09:05:09.942Z")}
{"_id" "K2","value" "VAL2","timest" (date "2021-09-26T09:05:10.234Z")}]
```

Results

testdb2.coll (after the merge)

```
{"_id": "K1", "value": "VAL1", "timest": {"$toDate": "2021-09-26T09:05:09.942Z"}}
{"_id": "K2", "value": "VAL3", "timest": {"$toDate": "2021-09-26T09:15:09.942Z"}}
{"_id": "K3", "value": "VAL4", "timest": {"$toDate": "2021-09-26T09:15:10.234Z"}}
```

Query
(instead of `$let` you could use `$$new`)

```js
client.db("testdb1").collection("coll").aggregate(
[
    {
      "$merge": {
        "into": {
          "db": "testdb2",
          "coll": "coll"
        },
        "on": [
          "_id"
        ],
        "let": {
          "p_ROOT": "$$ROOT"
        },
        "whenMatched": [
          {
            "$replaceRoot": {
              "newRoot": {
                "$cond": [
                  {
                    "$gt": [
                      "$$p_ROOT.timest",
                      "$timest"
                    ]
                  },
                  "$$p_ROOT",
                  "$$ROOT"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "whenNotMatched": "insert"
      }
    }
  ])
```

Comment: I understood the logic I have to follow, but using golang i have to use this function Aggregate pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.7.2/…. I have some problems converting your query into the one used by this library.

Comment: nested `bson.D{{...}}` can do it take a look at [this](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/quick-start-golang--mongodb--data-aggregation-pipeline) search for aggregation in go examples, it would be very easy to conver it, but will become bigger a bit, also for `$merge` read the docs, on how to output in collection.In Java for example we to `aggregate().toCollection();` if we have `$merge` or `$out` as last stage

Answer (score 0):

You can do following in an aggregation pipeline:

1. use `$unionWith` to combine the 2 collections
2. `$sort` to order them by `timest`
3. use `$first` to get the latest document
4. use `$replaceRoot` to get the final form your want

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QO0NA8mn5nt) for your reference.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understood the logic I have to follow, but using golang i have to use this function **Aggregate** https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.7.2/mongo#Collection.Aggregate.

I have some problems converting your syntax with the one used in this library, which needs bson.D for the query.

Comment: solution is nice and simple, but it doesn't work if collections are in different database, and OP has them in different databases.